# password_verify using password_hash error to store user in session at login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, passwords

I'm having a issue with password_hash, when i login i want to bring the user logged in Session, but do not work when i use password verify, the ECHO return nothing. How i can solve this? Thanks
This is my code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once("../Backend/conexao_db.php");

if((isset($_POST['txt_usuario'])) && (isset($_POST['txt_senha']))) {
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txt_usuario']); 
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txt_senha']);
    $passwordhash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Usuario WHERE email = '$usuario' && senha = '$pass'";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    if ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario)) {
        if (password_verify($pass, $passwordhash)) {


        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];
        if ($_SESSION['empresaID'] == "") {
            echo $_SESSION['usuarioId'];

            } else {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

This code work perfectly when i not use password_verify.

Comment: well probably that `$_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resuenter code hereltado['id'];` would throw an error with all those spaces in it

Comment: i'm sorry, was me when i put code here, i fixed it. please read again. thanks

Comment: and where is `$senha` coming from?  and without knowing how passwrd_verify works, I can't tell you why it's crashing

Comment: i fixed, i was translating the code to get easy to understand. $senha is the password , now $pass.

Comment: then it looks like something is bad in password_verify....that's all I can see, the other items appear to be fine

Comment: only work with no hash or md5. using password_hash need the password_verify (i think), when i use it, the code do not return the user logged in session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your'e doing there is useless, because you're testing the password hash you just created for matching with itself. This would always be true.

Without knowing your Session-Variables I would guess that `if ($_SESSION['empresaID'] == "")` is causing your error, unless you set it elsewhere.

But to improve your code:

You should store the hash in the database and test the result for a match with the inputted password.
Goal of this procedure is that you don't have to store the password in plaintext in your database.

Also, please use prepared statements to prevent SQL-injection. In my example I used [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php).

With prepared statements you can avoid `mysqli_real_escape_string` - it would change the password if there are any special characters in it.

```
if((!empty($_POST['txt_usuario'])) && (!empty($_POST['txt_senha']))) {
  $usuario = $_POST['txt_usuario'];
  $pass = $_POST['txt_senha'];

  // returns a connection to pdo
  $conn = Database::connectPDO();
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_Usuario WHERE email = :email');
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $usuario);

  if($stmt->execute()) {
    while($user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      if(password_verify($pass, $user['senha'])) {
         echo 'success';
       }
     }
  }
}
```

So, if you're adding an user, you should store the password hashed in the database for this function to work:

```
if((!empty($_POST['txt_usuario'])) && (!empty($_POST['txt_senha']))) {
  $usuario = $_POST['txt_usuario'];
  $pass = $_POST['txt_senha'];

  $hashedPassword = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  $conn = Database::connectPDO();
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_Usuario (email, senha) VALUES (:email, : senha)');
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $usuario);
  $stmt->bindParam(':senha', $hashedPassword);

  if($stmt->execute()) {
    echo 'successfully registered';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! you saved me.

Comment: About the if ($_SESSION['empresaID'] == "") i need verify if the value stored in $_SESSION exist or not to redirect the user to a specific page, this just don't work with password_verify, i don't know why, cause work with md5 or with no hash.